# Can I assign values to non-leaf nodes in a YAML hierarchy?

Tags: yaml, properties-file, snakeyaml

Is it possible to create an equivalent YAML-representation of the content of this .properties-file?

```
foo=Hello
foo.bar=World
```

I have tried the following:

```
foo: Hello
  bar: World
```

But that doesn't appear to cut it as the parser spits out an error:

> mapping values are not allowed here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [specifications](http://yaml.org/spec/history/2001-05-26.html) (see section 2.4.1), a node can only be followed by one of: scalar, map, list, or reference.  So, no, it cannot have a value assigned to it as well.

Comment: That's a link to a draft for version 1.0. You should rather link to the [1.2](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) and [1.1](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/) specs